# ATTiny861A fast PWM mode not working

Tags: pwm, timer, attiny, pll

For a couple of hours, I struggle to find the source of my PWM output to not generate a PWM signal. I changed register values to explicitly show their contents - I hope it will make the diagnostics easier. My goal is to generate a PWM signal with a variable duty cycle, clocked with PLL 64 MHz output, attached to OC1B, a non-inverting comparator. I've already tested different combinations of TCNT1/OCR1B/OCR1C values to see if ANY sign of response can be seen - with no effect.

Here's my code:

```
void initPWM()
{
    cli();
    while(!(PLLCSR & (1 << PLOCK)));
    PLLCSR |= (1 << PCKE);
    TCCR1A = (0<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (1<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (0<<PWM1A) | (1<<PWM1B);
    TCCR1B = (0<<PWM1X) | (0<<PSR1) | (0<<DTPS11) | (0<<DTPS10) | (0<<CS13) | (0<<CS12) | (0<<CS11) | (1<<CS10);
    TCCR1C = (0<<COM1A1S) | (0<<COM1A0S) | (0<<COM1B1S) | (0<<COM1B0S) | (0<<COM1D1) | (0<<COM1D0) | (0<<PWM1D);
    TCCR1D = (0<<FPIE1) | (0<<FPEN1) | (0<<FPNC1) | (0<<FPES1) | (0<<FPAC1) | (0<<FPF1) | (0<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
    TCCR1E = (0<<OC1OE5) | (0<<OC1OE4) | (0<<OC1OE3) | (0<<OC1OE2) | (0<<OC1OE1) | (0<<OC1OE0);
    TCNT1 = 0x00;
    DT1 = 0x00;
    OCR1B = 0x00;
    OCR1C = 0xFF;
    sei();
}

void setDutyCycle(uint8_t new_duty)
{
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) 
    {
        OCR1B = new_duty;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    wdt_disable(); // Watchdog disabled to make sure it's not the source of constant reset
    cli();
    PLLCSR |= (1<<PLLE);
    DDRB |= (1 << PB3); // OC1B SET AS OUTPUT
    CLKPR = 0x80;
    CLKPR = 0x00;
    MCUCR &= ~(1 << PUD);
    sei();

initPWM();
setDutyCycle(128);
while(1)
{}

}
```

I think it's worth mentioning that if I want to toggle the PB3 value manually before PWM initialization, it's perfectly responsive. No physical short circuit there. *edit* Not only before PWM init, but also after, e.g. in a while(1) loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not write to TCCR1C. If you have to change TCCR1C from its default value, use `|=` to set individual bits. From the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc8197.pdf), page 116:

```
TCCR1C - Timer/Counter1 Control Register C

Bits 5:4 – COM1B1S, COM1B0S: Comparator B Output Mode, Shadow Bits 1 and 0

These are shadow bits of COM1B1 and COM1B0 in TCCR1A. Writing to bits COM1B1S
and COM1B0S will also change bits COM1B1 and COM1B0 in TCCR1A.
Similary, changes written to bits COM1B1 and COM1B0 in TCCR1A will show here.
```

You're clearing COM1B0 and COM1B1 in TCCR1A by writing all zeros to TCCR1C, which mirrors these bits, thereby disabling the PWM output.

Alternatively, you can write zero to these bits in TCCR1A and only set them later when you write TCCR1C.